# Worksheet cell custom names access value in VBA

Tags: vba

Lets say I have a cell C1 and I define the name of it as follows below:
[image]

How can I access this cell in VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Name` which refers to a `Range` (a Cell is a `Range`) can be accessed by name:

```
MsgBox Range("asc_set_field").Value
```

If the `Name` is scoped to the `Workbook` (default), the above should work. If it is scoped to the `Worksheet`, you'll need to refer also to the worksheet:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet name") ' Modify as needed
MsgBox ws.Range("asc_set_field").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

To access it simply write:

```
Range("act_sec_field").Select
```

For more information on this you can visit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823060.aspx